# Finding an equation for velocity and acceleration

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, differentiation

I'm trying to derive an equation for the velocity and acceleration of an object undergoing simple harmonic motion.

I have the equation for displacement: $x = A\sin (2 \pi ft)$

If I differentiate the equation with respect to $t$ then I should get an equation for the velocity and if I differentiate again, I should get an equation for the acceleration, right?

So if I differentiate once, I get: $v = 2 \pi f\cos (2 \pi ft)$

If I differentiate again, I get: $a = -2 \pi fsin (2 \pi ft)$

However, I don't think these equations are correct. Am I making a silly mistake?

N.b. This isn't homework, I'm making extra revision notes :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is correct, but your calculations of the derivative are not.

$v = \frac{dx}{dt}$ where $x=A sin(2 \pi f t)$ would be $A 2 \pi f cos(2 \pi f t)$. Then $a = \frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = - A (2 \pi f)^2 sin(2 \pi f t)$.

Answer (score 0):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_harmonic_motion#Dynamics_of_simple_harmonic_motion:

$x=A \sin{(\omega t)}$

$v=A\omega \cos{(\omega t)}$

$a=-A\omega^2 \sin{(\omega t)}$

where $\omega=2\pi f$

This is because:

$\frac{d}{dx} \left( \sin{u} \right) = \cos{u} \, \frac{du}{dx}$

$\frac{d}{dx} \left( \cos{u} \right) = -\sin{u} \, \frac{du}{dx}$

See http://www.intmath.com/differentiation-transcendental/1-derivative-sine-cosine-tangent.php for derivatives of $\sin{u}$ and $\cos{u}$.

Comment: Your 2nd and 3rd equations are incorrect.

Comment: The 2nd equation has a rogue minus sign, but the 3rd equation looks correct. Am I missing an obvious mistake?

Comment: Yes, the second equation has a rogue minus sign. I put in an proposed edit to fix it.